# Change the color of a character-pointtype in gnuplot

Tags: character, gnuplot

I am trying to set the color of a character-defined point type in gnuplot. Although I can select the desire color of a system defined point type, I cannot do the same with the character-defined one. Below I present a minimal example.

```
set samples 5
set term pdf
set o "mwe.pdf"

p x with points lt rgb "violet" pt "V",\
  x with points lt rgb "violet" pt 2
  
set o
```

The result looks like this:

[image: The output of the example.]

<sub>I also tried to set the color with the `lc variable` method and feeding the keyword `using` with a column `("#005893")`, buit it still doesn't change the color.</sub>

### Question

How can I set the color of the letter to achieve something like this:

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following works for me.

```
reset session
set samples 5

plot x with points pt "V" tc rgb "red" font ",20", \
  x with points lt rgb "red" pt 2 ps 3
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Character point types are rendered by the same driver routine that handles labels and other text.  Therefore the color is taken from the current font and font properties apply, including color:

```
set sample 11
plot sin(x) with point pointtype "µ" textcolor rgb "violet" font "/:Bold,15"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `textcolor` instead of `linecolor` or `linetype` to change the point type defined by a character, as others pointed out already. See the [gnuplot documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.3/gnuplot.pdf#page=65).